# Android instrumentation does not start on a second device

Tags: android, gradle, automated-tests, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation

Since some time, when I run an instrumentation test on a device (emulator) and try to start another test on a second device in parallel, I get the following exception:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
>
> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\Android\MyApp\app\build\outputs\androidTest-results\connected\name_of_the_first_device\logcat-MyApp.TestClassName-TestName.txt:
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

The problem seems to be, that the build process tries to access a file from the first test device, which is already blocked. But I'm using a different device and try to run a different test.

The reason why I do that is because some of the tests are very large and therefore I try to spread them to several devices, so I get my results faster. The machine I run the tests on, has a hell of performance, so it can't be a problem of the resources ;-).

When I did the described actions some months ago, it worked properly, so I guess it's due to some updates (probably in Gradle or whatever). But I installed several updates since then, so it can't just be a problem of the current version.

**Update** - Two more inputs:

1. I recently switcht to using hilt and therefore created my own `TestRunner`, because an Application annotated with `@HiltApplication` cannot be used for tests, so I had to create a custom one for testing which needs to be run in a custom `TestRunner` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#custom-application).
2. When I run the same tests on multiple devices using "Select Multiple Devices" dropdown in Android Studio it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates a conflict over a build-and-run output file on your development computer, not on the Android test device. That is, it's trying to do another build-and-run in the same build output directory that the running test is using for purposes like the test's logcat output.

My first thought is to try duplicating `androidTest` to another build target. Same contents, different target name, different output directory. That workaround seems likely to get past this limitation (but with new limitations) and to help debug the problem. But the `name_of_the_first_device` subdirectory suggests that it can keep a logcat output file per test device, so the real question is how to get the test runner to use a separate subdirectory per test device.

Second thought is to point you to the the docs, [Run Tests with Multiple Devices](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/tradefed/architecture/advanced/multi-device) and [Shard Tests](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/tradefed/architecture/advanced/sharding).

With a custom `TestRunner`, see [Write a Sharded IRemoteTest Test Runner](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/tradefed/testing/through-tf/sharded-runner) (and other pages in the "Tradefed" section) on making it a "shardable" test runner which enables the test infrastructure to distribute the full test execution over several devices.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. As I don't know nothing about what you explain, let me ask some questions ;-). Your first thought means that I duplicate the gradle task and name and call it differently, right?
While I read about shard tests I had the following thoughts: 1. I recently changed to hilt and therefore created my own TestRunner. Could that cause the problem? 2. When I run the same tests on multiple devices using "Select Multiple Devices" dropdown in Android Studio it works. Doesn't this mean sharding is possible?

Comment: Yes, for your custom TestRunner, see https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/tradefed/testing/through-tf/sharded-runner (and the other pages in the Trade Federation section) about how to make it support sharding. The "Select Multiple Devices" success is a very good sign. The idea of duplicating the `androidTest` build target would just be a limited workaround but maybe also useful to way to debug the problem.